# How to use this jQuery plugin in Angular 4?

Tags: jquery, html, angular, plugins

I'm developing a Web Application using Angular 4 (with TypeScript language).

I have a problem and I hope it's easy to solve it.

I would like to use this jQuery plugin (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in my application to view the Multiple Select.

The problem is that I can't import it into my application (the plugin seems to work only with html static pages!).

I tried to include in the file `angular-cli.json` 
the dependencies on .js files, in this way:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/chosen-npm/public/chosen.jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/chosen-npm/public/chosen.jquery.js"]
```

But unfortunately I can't see the multiple selection correctly. I do not understand how to use this plugin.

Can anyone help me, maybe try it on an angular application?

Comment: if its in jquery and you want to use that in your angular component, you can do that by injecting jquery in your component and use `$` to call all of them. there are I think many way

Answer (score 0):

use like this :

**.angular-cli.json**
add your jquery javascript in scripts array in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
],
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: he was asking about chosen, a jquery plugin.  jquery itself isn't that hard.